# Subtraction value with same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm stuck with my query using Oracle, please help me.

This is my table:

| id | cust | order | qty | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | abc | 10.000 | 2000 | 8000 |
| 0001 | abc | 10.000 | 4000 | 6000 |
| 0001 | abc | 10.000 | 4000 | 6000 |
| 0002 | bcd | 5000 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 0003 | fgh | 3000 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 0004 | ghj | 5000 | NULL | 5000 |

result that i want :

| id | cust | order | qty | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | abc | 10.000 | 2000 | 8000 |
| 0001 | abc | 10.000 | 4000 | 4000 |
| 0001 | abc | 10.000 | 4000 | 0 |
| 0002 | bcd | 5000 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 0003 | fgh | 3000 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 0004 | ghj | 5000 | NULL | 5000 |

value = order - qty

So, the calculation based on same id and same cust, they are subtract from rows before, if id and cust does not same, they subtract normally.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For a given id and cust, how do you decide which row is "first" and which is "second" etc.? In your example, you have two rows, with qty 2000 and 4000. What tells you (more importantly, what tells ***me***, and what tells ***Oracle***) that the row with qty of 2000 should be first, and the row with 4000 should be second, and not the other way around? Other than that, the problem seems trivial (using analytic `sum()`).

Comment: You should at the very least also include what the output table looks like here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I believe what he showed is the output. The input must have `null` in the last column (or the `value` column doesn't even exist in the table; it shouldn't exist there).

Comment: Voting to close as unclear, and most users won't have your insight to figure this out (I know I certainly didn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you have another column which tells you the order in which the `qty` should be subtracted from the `order` column and have called this the `datetime` column (but you can use whatever column you have available to provide a deterministic ordering of the rows). Given that, you can calculate the `value` using an analytic `SUM` function:

```sql
SELECT id,
       cust,
       datetime,
       order_total,
       qty,
       order_total
         - SUM( COALESCE( qty, 0 ) )
             OVER ( PARTITION BY id, cust, order_total ORDER BY datetime )
         AS value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, cust, datetime, order_total, qty ) AS
SELECT '0001',  'abc',  DATE '2021-01-01', 10000,   2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001',  'abc',  DATE '2021-01-02', 10000,   4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0001',  'abc',  DATE '2021-01-03', 10000,   4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0002',  'bcd',  DATE '2021-01-01', 5000,    2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0003',  'fgh',  DATE '2021-01-01', 3000,    1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0004',  'ghj',  DATE '2021-01-01', 5000,    NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID   | CUST | DATETIME  | ORDER_TOTAL |  QTY | VALUE
> :--- | :--- | :-------- | ----------: | ---: | ----:
> 0001 | abc  | 01-JAN-21 |       10000 | 2000 |  8000
> 0001 | abc  | 02-JAN-21 |       10000 | 4000 |  4000
> 0001 | abc  | 03-JAN-21 |       10000 | 4000 |     0
> 0002 | bcd  | 01-JAN-21 |        5000 | 2000 |  3000
> 0003 | fgh  | 01-JAN-21 |        3000 | 1000 |  2000
> 0004 | ghj  | 01-JAN-21 |        5000 | null |  5000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5bf4870184760de74251a11bd8c3294c)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below - using `lag()`

```
select id,cust,orders,qty,
orders-qty-coalesce(lag(qty) over(partition by id,cust order by qty),0) as value
from tablename
```

OUTPUT:

```
id          cust        orders  qty    value
0001        abc         10000   2000    8000
0001        abc         10000   4000    4000
0002        bcd         5000    2000    3000
0003        fgh         3000    1000    2000
```

Comment: Besides guessing at the `order by` rule, your query will only work if there are at most two rows per id/customer. What if there are five rows (and the requirement is the same)?

Comment: that's query almost correct Mr.Fahmi thanks, but in other case i have more two rows per id/customer and i use that query the calculations not correctly, the query only work  if i have max two rows per id/customer. Someone could help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to partition by id and order by id and qty.
You can try

```
Select id,  cust,   order,  qty,  order-coalesce(sum(qty) over (partition by id order by id,  qty),0) as value from myTable;
```